# How to ask a user confirmation when opening a binary or a big file in vim?

Tags: vim

*(Sorry for bad English.)*

Say, when I try to see binary file in `less`, it ask me a confirmation:

```
$ less `which less`
"/usr/bin/less" may be a binary file.  See it anyway?
```

How to set up `vim` for the same behavior? Also I want to `vim` will ask a confirmation when I try to open too big (e.g. >10MB, maybe text) file.

Answer (score 0):

Vim doesn't have such option.

But you can write yourself a wrapper (let's call it vimwarp.sh) which could check the file size & type and ask you to open it anyway)

and if you want to do this nicely, you can write an alias for that command in your .bashrc

```
alias vim=vimwrap.sh
```

Comment: It is dirty solution. Vim has `.vimrc` and own powerfull language with autocommands, etc. I sure vim able to make all itself.